# OS detection using nmap for a particular IP address

Tags: nmap

I am trying to determine the OS of a particular IP address using `nmap`. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class NmapFlags {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {

      String[] cmdarray = { "nmap", "-O", "66.110.59.130" };//

      // example trying to find the OS or device detials of this Ip address//
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          process.getInputStream()));
      String s;
      while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);

      }

      r.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

After running this code output I got is:

```
All 1000 scanned ports on 66.110.59.130 are filtered
All 1000 scanned ports on 66.110.59.130 are filtered
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 246.06 seconds
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 246.06 seconds**
```

Are there any other `nmap` flags I can use to detect the device type? I tried -A option. I need to find the device details at each hop of trace route.

Comment: This is not a [tag:java] question, this is an `nmap` question. You should ask on [su]

Answer (score 6):

Nmap performs “active fingerprinting” (it sends packets then analyse the response) to guess what the remote Operating System is. These probes are quite intrusive and I‘d recommend reading more about it (http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-fingerprint-format.html).

"Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details" means that the probes are contradictory or too broad.
For example in a NAT scenario, some port scans return the router information (e.q. Cisco iOS), some other probes return the real host specifications (e.q. Windows).

The best way to understand how the network is designed is to rely on your own judgment based on different probes and output.

IP ID sequence, fingerprint analysis and service detection (-sV) can help:

e.q. If 3389 is open, then the OS running is a Windows.

e.q. if IP ID sequence varies then the target might be multiple (Load balanced).

Your analysis of the network traffic will always be more accurate than what nmap attempt to guess in an automated way.